# Debian LITE Smooth Slide Show

Tags: bash, debian, raspberry-pi3, slideshow, raspbian

I'm interested in utilizing my `Raspberry Pi 3` for advertising purposes. I'd like to create a slideshow that can display both videos and images, and I want to be able to iterate through all the media files located in a specific folder, as I have limited control over the network and need to retrieve these files from a cloud source.

I currently have a code snippet that uses `fbi`and `vlc` to achieve this, but I'm facing an issue where the command-line briefly appears after each image transition. After video there is no such problem.

I've managed to mitigate this issue with the clear command, but it's still bothering me. I'm wondering if anyone has suggestions for a smoother way to accomplish this without the command-line interruptions.

Here my codesnipped:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Define the directory where your images are stored
MEDIA_FOLDER="/home/pi/slide_show/test"

# Create an array of media files
media_files=("$MEDIA_FOLDER"/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif,mp4})

clear
setterm -cursor off

# Iterate through media files and display them
while true; do
    for media_file in "${media_files[@]}"; do
        if [[ -f "$media_file" ]]; then
            if [[ "$media_file" == *.mp4 ]]; then
                vlc -f --one-instance --no-xlib -I dummy "$media_file" vlc://quit >/dev/null 2>&1
            else
                clear
                fbi -a -b -u -noverbose -1 -t 5 "$media_file" >/dev/null 2>&1
                clear
            fi
        fi
    done
done
```

UPDATE:

So I now have at least a smooth way for images. When switching between image and video there is still  a short amount of time a black screen.

```bash
DISPLAYTIME=10
MEDIA_FOLDER=""

# Function to kill display processes
killer() {
    sudo pkill -9 -x "fbi"
    sudo pkill -x "mpv"
    sleep 2
}

# Function to display images and videos in terminal
display() {
    local image_files="$1"
    local video_files="$2"
    killer

    if [[ -n "$image_files" && -n "$video_files" ]]; then
        while true; do
            sudo fbi -a -r 5 -t $DISPLAYTIME -T 1 --noverbose -1 $image_files >/dev/null 2>&1 &
            disown
            sleep $((IMAGE_FILES_COUNT * DISPLAYTIME))
            pkill -9 -x "fbi" >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &
            mpv --fs --cache-secs=10 --fs-screen=1 "$video_files" >/dev/null 2>&1
            clear
        done
    elif [ -n "$image_files" ]; then
        clear
        sudo fbi -a -r 5 -t $DISPLAYTIME -T 1 --noverbose $image_files >/dev/null 2>&1
    elif [ -n "$video_files" ]; then
        clear
        mpv --fs --cache-secs=10 --loop=inf --fs-screen=1 "$video_files" >/dev/null 2>&1
    fi
}

# Function to handle the main display logic
handle_display() {
    local image_files=$(find "$MEDIA_FOLDER" -type f \( -iname "*.jpg" -o -iname "*.jpeg" -o -iname "*.png" -o -iname "*.gif" \))
    local video_files=$(find "$MEDIA_FOLDER" -type f \( -iname "*.mp4" -o -iname "*.mkv" -o -iname "*.avi" -o -iname "*.ogg" -o -iname "*.mov" \))
    display "$image_files" "$video_files"
}

# Function to handle the main loop
main_loop() {
    while true; do
        sudo kill "$DISPLAYPID"
        sleep 2
        killer
        if [ -d "$MEDIA_FOLDER" ] && [ "$(ls -A "$MEDIA_FOLDER")" ]; then
            handle_display &
            DISPLAYPID=$!
        else
            killer
            clear
        fi
        sleep 10
    done
}
```

Comment: What's `fbi`? Is it a console application? Could you use a graphical application instead?

Comment: As an aside, capturing the media files in an array outside the loop and then repeatedly looping over that seems like a small waste of memory as well as a robustness problem. If you'd expand the wildcard each time in the loop, you would be able to add and remove files to the media directory while the script is running.

Comment: @tripleee do you thing `feh` would not create those black pausees?

Comment: I have no idea what `feh` is either.

Comment: okay what did you mean then?
I am runnning a raspberry that has no desktop environment

Comment: I'm trying to get you to clarify your question. Please [edit] with links to the third-party resources you are using here.

Comment: @tripleee `fbi` is available on Debian `apt show fbi`. It's a *frame buffer* image viewer. They don't rely on X server. So it's a *console*, but *graphical* application

Comment: @Muddyblackk did you try to play with `-T` switch (for addressing another *vt*).

Comment: Yes but then i always have the problem of multiple fbi processes which interfere with each other and `pkill PID` somehow not affecting them

Comment: Well I got it to work at least for images when I have some more time I will make it for videos too and then update this question :)

Comment: Another solution could be to play with 2 VT and a *fifo*: `mkfifo $HOME/fifo; while read file < $HOME/fifo;do fbi -t 5 "$file";done` on a VT, then play with `chvt` from another script...

Comment: look about `openvt`, `chvt` and play with parallel scripts...

Comment: Yeah I will try that to improve it more

Comment: Copy/paste your script into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it tells you about. Also, don't store lists of file names (or anything else) in a scalar variable and then reference that variables contents unquoted, instead store them in an array and reference them quoted, e.g. `readarray -t image_files < <(find . -type f ...)` and then `fbi ... "${image_files[@]}" ...` to save yourself from lots of obscure errors.